# How to get a column with the bit format in a view?

Tags: mysql, view, format, boolean

Hi I have a SQL query that I want to save as a view. The query has the following line:
IF (TC.exportaComprobante = 1, true, false) as flag
When I see the structure of the VIEW, the flag field has the following format:
BIGINT (20) and I want it to be BIT

How I can fix it?

Comment: Try the CAST or the CONVERT functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT *, CAST(IF(true, 1, 0) AS BINARY) FROM test;
```